# JQuery AJAX wont fire after the second time

Tags: javascript, events, serialization, jquery

This is scratching my head, the first time I click, it submit just fine with the alert data.msg .But the second time , the ajax only does nothing, the alert "end here" still fire so I assume no problem with event click. Whats wrong with my ajax? because of the serialize thing?

```
                $('#inv-btn-submit').live('click',function(e) {

                    $.ajax({
                        type : 'POST',
                        url : '<?= base_url();?>main/insertInvoice',
                        dataType : 'json',
                        data: {product_list:$('.namabarang').serializeArray(),
                            qty_list : $('.qty').serializeArray(),
                            cost_list : $('.cost').serializeArray(),
                            customer_meta:$('#customer input, textarea').serializeArray()
                        },

                        success : function(data){
                           alert(data.msg);


                        },
                        error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            alert('There was an error. ');
                        }
                    });//end of ajax
                    alert("end here");
                    return false;

                });// end of button click
```

Comment: Can u see if the xhr request is sent using browser tool like Chrome's developer tool?

Comment: I can't immediately see what's wrong here (possibly too early for me!) but if you open up developer tools/firebug/something similar, do you see what request is being sent to the server?

Comment: Can you see if it tries to send the post (in firebug/ie developer/chrome developer etc), or dosent it get that far?

Comment: The "end here" alert is unrelated to the AJAX call, which is asynchronous... actually they're not executed in sequence. Have you tried to debug it with Firebug, inserting two breakpoints in success and error callbacks?

Comment: If you are using IE, just make sure that you have 'cache' disabled by this option: cache:false

Comment: I may be VERY wrong in saying this, but remove your 'return false' from there and see if that works, as when it hits there it will stop.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to turn off asynchronization just for his call by 
setting. 
async:   false

```
 $('#inv-btn-submit').live('click',function(e) {

                $.ajax({
                    type : 'POST',
                    url : '<?= base_url();?>main/insertInvoice',
                    dataType : 'json',
                    data: {product_list:$('.namabarang').serializeArray(),
                        qty_list : $('.qty').serializeArray(),
                        cost_list : $('.cost').serializeArray(),
                        customer_meta:$('#customer input, textarea').serializeArray()
                    },

                    async: false,

                    success : function(data){
                       alert(data.msg);


                    },
                    error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert('There was an error. ');
                    }
                });//end of ajax
                alert("end here");
                return false;

            });//
```

Answer (score 0):

serializeArray works on a form selector e.g:  `$('form').serializeArray();` will return an array of data to post to the requested URI/URL not sure it would work on the individual inputs.
Notice, I have put die() there before live, as this would kill any previous events.
maybe, you may need to add the `e.preventDefault();` as well, to stop the form refreshing the page on submit.

```
 $('#inv-btn-submit').die().live('click',function(e) {
   var get_data = $('form').serializeArray();
   $.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : '<?= base_url();?>main/insertInvoice',
    dataType : 'json',
    data: get_data,
    success : function(data){
         alert(data.msg);
    },
    error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
       alert('There was an error. ');
    }
 });//end of ajax
 alert("end here");
 return false;
});// end of button click
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can also do this:

```
...
data: {product_list: return $('.namabarang').serializeArray(),
...
```

About the die() method called before live() method I guess there's no need. 
My 2 cents!

Answer (score 0):

The console tells alot, it still sent the post data and I realize the second time I submit I have to update that invoice but my php script went to the wrong direction and has no json data being echoed, its weird that the error function did not fire if there is no callback data. Thanks guys for the hints.